# In C, if this isn't an address constant, what is it?

Tags: c, c99

What, exactly, is `numbers` in the following declaration, if it is not an address constant?

```
int main() {
    int numbers[3] = {1,2,3};
    return 0;
}
```

Disassembling the program shows that 1, 2, and 3 are dynamically placed on the local stack space, rather than the whole array being treated as a constant. Hence, `{1,2,3}` does not have static storage duration, so `numbers` is *not* an address constant, as per the C99 spec.

C99, Section 6.6.9: "An address constant is a null pointer, a pointer to an lvalue designating an object of static storage duration, or a pointer to a function designator..."

However, adding the line `numbers++` after the declaration causes the following compile error in GCC 4.1.2:

`error: invalid lvalue in increment`

So it is constant, but isn't an address constant. Does anybody know the official name of this type of constant in C99 (or similar)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`numbers` is a non-constant, automatic, array variable of the function `main`.

Because it is automatic and non-constant it *can not* have static storage.

because it is an array variable (and *not* you'll notice a pointer) it can not be incremented.

Note that you *can* do

```
int main() {
    int numbers[3] = {1,2,3};
    int *n = numbers+1;
    n++;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds plausible, but the term "array variable" is not in the C99 spec at all. Is this the exact distinction being drawn?

Comment: @Carlo: I can't answer you abot the standard. Just about the semantics. You can't use the post-increment operator on `numbers` because it is an array-typed variable, and that operation is not defined on arrays; and it's storage can not live in the data segment (or any other mechanism for deploying static storage) because the variable is non-constant and automatic.

Comment: Found it! In Section 6.3.2.1.3, it states that "an expression that has type 'array of type' is converted to an expression with type 'pointer to type' that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue."

Comment: Basically, there is an essential distinction between "array" and "pointer" variables, which is that the former is not an lvalue. Thanks!

Comment: @Carlo: Er... No, your final conclusion is absolutely incorrect. Array *is* an lvalue. The result of array-to-pointer conversion is not an lvalue, but the array itself is. For example, if you declare `double d`, variable `d` is an lvalue, but the result of `(int) d` expression is not an lvalue. The same thing happens with an array. `numbers` is an lvalue, but `(int *) numbers` is not an lvalue, except that in this case the `(int *)` conversion is performed implictly.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: the former is converted to a pointer type which is not an lvalue (although true pointers are lvalues).

Comment: Actually, a question: You say an array is an lvalue. But how could you use it as an lvalue? It can't be something like `numbers[0] = 1`, since `numbers[0]` is an int, not an array.

Comment: An array is a lvalue, but not a *modifiable* lvalue. (6.3.2.1) And the operand of the postfix increment must be a *modifiable* lvalue. (6.5.2.4)

Comment: @Carlo: In the expression `&numbers`, `numbers` is being used as an lvalue.  I *believe* that's the only case in which you can demonstrate the "lvalueness" of an array.

Comment: @caf, there is one more case: When used as the operand of `sizeof`. (As used in the common idiom `nelem = sizeof a / sizeof a[0]`).

Comment: @schot: It's true that the array remains an lvalue when passed to `sizeof`, but since `sizeof` works on rvalues too, that doesn't really demonstrate that the array is an lvalue (to my mind, anyway).  Unary `&` on the other hand requires an lvalue.

Answer (score 11):

You seem to be inventing something that isn't really there, terminology-wise.

`numbers` is an array. It is an automatic object of type `int[3]`. It cannot be used to form address constants in C, since in C address constants require objects with static storage duration.

If your `numbers` was declared with static storage duration, then the result of array-to-pointer conversion applied to `numbers` would be an address constant. `numbers + 1` as well as `&numbers[2]` would also be address constant in that case.

You are right to note that `{ 1, 2, 3 }` doesn't have static storage duration. In fact, it has no storage duration at all. It is not an object, but merely a piece of syntactic sugar called *aggregate initializer*. If you wanted it to become an anonymous object, you'd have to use the *compound literal* syntax: `(int[]) { 1, 2, 3 }`, but it wouldn't work in the above context anyway.

`numbers++` will not compile simply because the result of array-to-pointer conversion is not an lvalue. You can't apply `++` to a non-lvalue. Whether something is constant or not is irrelevant.

You seem to making a strange conclusion that if you can't modify it it must be a constant. That's totally incorrect. In C terminology the property of being *constant* has very little to do with the property of being *modifiable*. The term *constant* refers to values that are known at *compile time*. Values that are not known at compile time are never called *constants*, even if they are not modifiable. This is an example of that: the address of an automatic array is not known at compile time, so even though that address is not modifiable, it is still not an *address constant*.

Comment: Yes. The fact that an array-to-pointer conversion is not an lvalue is what I was interested in. However, I was expecting a semantically cleaner distinction than the "an array is implicitly like a pointer except is not an lvalue" answer that the spec apparently gives.

Comment: @Carlo: That's *not* what the standard says.  It says that an array is an "aggregate type" (just like structure types) - an array is *"a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type"* .

Comment: @Carlo: Array is not "like a pointer" in general. Array is "like a pointer" only in a well-defined set of specific contexts. Operator `++` just happens to be one of those contexts.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays are not pointers; see section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not an address constant is because it's an address on the stack, and that location depends on what is above it in the call stack. Something can't be a constant if its value isn't known until run time.

It's not a variable either, which is why you can't increment it. It's just the name of a storage location, which happens to be an offset on the base pointer. `numbers[0]` is a valid l-value, but `numbers` is not.

Comment: Auto variables are typically allocated on a stack, but that is an implementation detail.  Some embedded-systems allocated automatic variables at link time (either recursion is forbidden, or possibly-recursive calls will copy the variables to a pseudo-stack).  Unfortunately, even when the auto variables are at linker-determined constant addresses, there's still AFAICT no way to exploit that fact within C.

Answer (score -1):

`numbers` can't be changed because it must always point to the first element in the array.

Comment: Right, I understand it's a constant. But what is the official name of this type of constant?

Comment: `numbers` can't be changed because it is an array, not a pointer.